# PHP CSRF Token code. Sufficient security?

Tags: php, sql, security, csrf

Having recently protected my site the best I can against XSS I am now in the process of protecting against CSRF, having watched and read some articles on the matter I have created the below code.

I would like to know whether my implementation is correct in using a string in the database to help security. Is the anything I should be doing differently?? Should I be checking the database on both sides???

Code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['register_token'])){

  $keytype = 'register';

  $getregisterkey = mysql_query("SELECT key FROM tokenkeys WHERE type='".$keytype."' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getregisterkey))
  {
$registerkey = mysql_real_escape_string($row['key']);
  }; 


  $_SESSION['register_token']=sha1(uniqid(rand(), TRUE).$registerkey);
  $_SESSION['register_token_time']=time();
}

<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['register_token'];?>" />



if($_POST['register_token']==$_SESSION['register_token']){
  $register_token_age=time()-$_SESSION['register_token_time'];
  if($register_token_age=>300){

    //process form
  } else{
    //valid token but expired
  }
} else{
  die('Access Forbidden')

}
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the output of a sql query?  Do you know what mysql_real_escape_string even does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSRF tokens are only as safe as the channel over which the page is sent.  Use `https` and only `https` on this form and only submit it to an `https` endpoint.  Otherwise a MITM can get your XSRF token from the form as it is served, or as it is submitted.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getregisterkey))
{
    $registerkey = mysql_real_escape_string($row['key']);
};
```

will never execute when there are zero rows which case you don't get much entropy from `$getregisterkey` when you later do

```
$_SESSION['register_token']=sha1(uniqid(rand(), TRUE).$registerkey);
```

so I would make sure that your implementation fails-fast if there are zero rows returned.  Maybe change to `if ($row = mysql_fetch_array(...)) { ... } else { /* abort */ }` since you get no benefit from extra rows.

The `rand()` needs to be either truly random or a [cryptographically strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) PRNG.

I am not familiar with PHP's standard libraries but [wikipedia] suggests `rand()` is not cryptographically strong.  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_password_generator) says

> There are proposals for adding strong random number generation to PHP.

[Strong cryptography in PHP](http://www.zimuel.it/en/strong-cryptography-in-php/) suggests using  `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`

> **Don’t use rand() or mt_rand()**
>
> To generate a cryptographically strong random number in PHP you have to use the function `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` of the OpenSSL library.

If you use weak randomness then an attacker can observe the numbers you generate (by requesting multiple version of the form and parsing out the hidden input) and use that to figure out what the next numbers might be and forge CSRF tokens.

If an attacker modify the `'register_token_time'` session property then they can avoid your XSRF checks.

For example, if you have a page that does

```
$_SESSION[$_POST['x']] = $_POST['y'];
```

then an attacker can POST

```
x=register_token&y=pwnd
```

to replace the register_token stored in the session and then send a post with

```
token=pwnd
```

and bypass your XSRF protection.

Comment: Taking into consideration your answer should I remove the database connection or implement it in another way? What do you mean by $_SESSION[$attackerControlledInput] = ... should I add something else??

Comment: @user1002916, please see my edits.  I tried to clarify both sections.

Comment: i don't get your point. If a session id is leaked because of a owasp a9 violation then you don't need to use CSRF,  you already have the entire session,  there is no point in riding on it.  its a chiken or the egg.

Comment: Also, no thats not session fixation,  thats poising the session variable name-space.  Session fixation is if the attacker creates a new session id and tricks a user into authenticating with that id.  This should be prevented with your php.ini cofnig.

Comment: @Rook, I think you're right about "session fixation".  I don't think I ever talk about session leaking, just ability of an attacker to predict the CSRF token.  Could you quote the text you're referring to when you talk about "if a session id is leaked..."?

Comment: @Rook, ok, so you are talking about "XSRF tokens are only as safe as the channel over which the page is sent...".  I think you are right.  I will remove the bit about using it in the clear.